# Scoping issue that won't let me set the state

Tags: typescript

In the following function:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';
1 export const useFetchErrors = (project_scan_id: number) => {
2     const [errors, setErrors] = useState<Array<String>>([]);
3     const [isErrorsFetchComplete, setIsErrorsFetchComplete] = useState<boolean>(false);
4     const {enqueueSnackbar, } = useSnackbar();
5     let string_project_scan_id: string | null = String(project_scan_id)
6     useEffect(() => {
7         if (string_project_scan_id != null){
8             const queryParams = {
9                     project_scan_id: string_project_scan_id
10                };
11
12        const URL: string = '/api/get_all_errors?' +
13                new URLSearchParams(queryParams).toString();
14
15            const fetchErrors = async () => {
16                try {
17                 
18                    let errorsArray: string[] = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'];
19                    console.log(errorsArray)
20                    setErrors(errorsArray)
21                } catch (e: any) {
22                    console.error(e);
23                    enqueueSnackbar(`Could not load errors! Error: ${e}`, {variant: 'error'});
24                } finally {
25                    setIsErrorsFetchComplete(true);
26                }
27            };
28
29            fetchErrors()
30    }}, []);
31    console.log(errors)
32    return [errors, isErrorsFetchComplete]
33}
```

I'm trying to set errors (a state which is initially a blank String array) to the String array on line 18 inside of the fetchErrors function inside of the useEffect function. For some reason, the console.log on line 19 isn't showing, and setErrors (setting the errors state array to the array on line 18) isn't working either because the log on line 31 shows a blank array. I imagine these are scope issues, but I'm not entirely sure. Why exactly am I having these issues?

Comment: 1 console.log does not work as you might think. 2 what is setErrors? You need to provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro it should be fully reproducible now